# Generic partial applied function in c#

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, functional-programming

There are binary serialization methods in some classes group. The algorithm is simple: recursive write all primitive type fields in all nested objects in some order. While structure of class may vary, I need some functionality for keeping track of data been written. So I end up with idea to store fields names and offset in binary stream in some `xml`.
Here the example interface method realization for serialization, which must be implemented in all class within that group:

```
public XElement mySerialize(BinaryWriter bw)
{
    var x = new XElement("Class0",
        serializeAndProduceLog(id, "id", bw, bw.Write),
        serializeAndProduceLog(classFieldString, "classFieldString", bw, bw.Write),
        serializeAndProduceLog(classFieldLong, "classFieldLong", bw, bw.Write),
        classFieldObject0.mySerialize(bw),
        classFieldList.Select(o => o.mySerialize)
    );
    return x;
}
```

Here are utility methods:

```
    private XElement serializeAndProduceLog<T>(T field, string name, BinaryWriter bw, Action<T> f)
    {
        return new XElement(name, new XAttribute("type", field.GetType()), new Attribute("offset", writeField(field, bw, f)));
    }

    private long writeField<T>(T v, BinaryWriter bw, Action<T> f)
    {
        var p = bw.BaseStream.Position;
        f(v);
        return bw.BaseStream.Position - p;
    }
```

`writeField` method performs binary writing operation and return amount of bytes has written.
I don't want to write bunch of overloaded wrappers for every `BinaryWriter.Write` overloaded instance, so generic argument `f` do the trick.
Now, since `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryWriter.Write` are always the same, my whim is to get rid of boring repetitive parameter passing. I want to introduce partially applied function like

```
Func<int, string, XElement> serializeAndProduceLogInt = (field, name) => serializeAndProduceLog(field, name, bw, bw.Write);
```

But with generic parameter instead of "int". Is this possible in C#?

Answer (score 1):

```
Func<T, string, XElement> SerializeAndProduceLogger<T>(BinaryWriter bw)
{
    var method = typeof(BinaryWriter).GetMethod("Write", new Type[] { typeof(T) });
    if(method == null) throw new ArgumentException("No overload of write for type");

    Action<T> act = f => { method.Invoke(bw, new object[] { f }) };
    return (T field, string name) => serializeAndProduceLog(field, name, bw, act);
}
```

Comment: This code looks very complex with reflection. I want to find way to infer types at compile time. But anyway, thanks.

Comment: @SergeyPrytkov - I'm fairly sure you can't do this without using reflection. Generics don't work well with overloads since there's no way to do specialisation of generic parameters at a method call site.